# Test self-signed certificate authentication webservice with SoapUI

Tags: spring, authentication, ssl, certificate, soapui

I'm using Spring webservice 2.2.x to implement self certificate authentication by using  `<x509/>`

In this way, **X509AuthenticationFilter** is expecting client certificate from **javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate**

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

How can I configure SoapUI to put client certificate there?
I have tried to configure JKS or PCS12 keystore as:

1. Show Project View -> WS-Security Configurations -> keyStore
2. Request Properties -> SSL KeyStore

But It doesn't work: **No client certificate found in request**

```
11:58:10.001 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:58:10.004 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
11:58:10.004 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
11:58:10.005 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/services'; against '/logout'
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'X509AuthenticationFilter'
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter - Checking secure context token: null
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter - No client certificate found in request.
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter - No client certificate found in request.
11:58:10.006 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter - No pre-authenticated principal found in request
11:58:10.007 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
11:58:10.007 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
11:58:10.007 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /services at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
11:58:10.007 [233950856@qtp-444127949-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After create project
2. Show Porject View -> WS-Security Configurations -> keystore
3. Add Client PCKS12 key here
4. WS-Security Configurations -> Outgoing WS-Secutity Configurations -> New Outgoing WSS Configuration -> with a arbitrary name
5. Then find "Sepcify unique name for configuration" under -> Fill in Keystore, Alias and Password(if there's is, usually empty)
6. save and configuration done